# DoctrineOrmMappingsPass not working as expected

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm writing a library + bundle for Symfony2. My model is in the library (`TNTExpress\Model`), and my doctrine mapping is in the bundle (`winzou\Bundle\TNTExpressBundle`).

I'm having a hard time figuring out an issue with the CompilerPass to tell Doctrine that the model for my mapping is not inside my bundle. I just followed http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/mapping_model_classes.html

My issue is that Doctrine is still looking for my models inside the bundle:

```
    [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
    Class 'winzou\Bundle\TNTExpressBundle\Entity\Expedition' does not exist
```

Here is my bundle class with the compilerPass called:

```
namespace winzou\Bundle\TNTExpressBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineOrmMappingsPass;

class winzouTNTExpressBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createXmlMappingDriver(
            array($this->getConfigFilesPath() => $this->getModelNamespace())
        ));
    }

    protected function getConfigFilesPath()
    {
        return sprintf(
            '%s/Resources/config/doctrine',
            $this->getPath()
        );
    }

    protected function getModelNamespace()
    {
        return 'TNTExpress\Model';
    }
}
```

And my mapping is in `@winzouTNTExpressBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Expedition.orm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping">

    <entity name="TNTExpress\Model\Expedition" table="winzou_tntexpress_expedition">
        <id name="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <field name="parcelResponses" column="parcel_responses" type="object" />
        <field name="PDFLabels" column="pdf_labels" type="text" />
        <field name="pickUpNumber" column="pickup_number" type="string" nullable="true" />
    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

I can see in the getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService method in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php that both namespaces are defined for my model namespace:

```
protected function getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService()
{
    // Good config path, wrong namespace (inside the bundle)
    $c = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\SimplifiedXmlDriver(array('...',  'D:\\www\\TNTExpressBundle\\Resources\\config\\doctrine' => 'winzou\\Bundle\\TNTExpressBundle\\Entity'));
    $c->setGlobalBasename('mapping');

    $d = new \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain();
    // ...
    $d->addDriver($c, 'winzou\\Bundle\\TNTExpressBundle\\Entity');
    // ...
    // Good config path, good namespace (inside the library)
    $d->addDriver(new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver(new \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\SymfonyFileLocator(array('D:\\www\\TNTExpressBundle/Resources/config/doctrine' => 'TNTExpress\\Model'), '.orm.xml')), 'TNTExpress\\Model');

    $e = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
    $e->setEntityNamespaces(array('...', 'winzouTNTExpressBundle' => 'winzou\\Bundle\\TNTExpressBundle\\Entity'));


    // ...
}
```

Finaly, if I avoid the call of `MappingDriverChain::addDriver($c)` by hardly putting an if in this `addDriver` method, then everything works fine.

My question is : how do I avoid this wrong namespace to be called on the MappingDriverChain?
Did I do something wrong using the CompilerPass? I just followed the documentation here...

Thanks!

Comment: I confess I did not wade through your code.  You can specify entity and mapping directories in config.yml and avoid the pass stuff completely.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that this is a reusable bundle, so I can't go for the config.yml solution ;)

Comment: @abacco Have you ever found a solution for this? I find documentation is rather abstract in Symfony about this and difficult to work out what to do in these cases